# Problems creating a Tkinter box in program

Tags: python, tkinter

The `frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=250)` is not properly creating a Tkinter window. Could you find the problem and tell me what it is. If it helps I do have the rest of the code.

```
def clicking_pad(worker_1):
    root = Tk()

    global left_click

    def left_click(store: object) -> object:
        return store

    global right_click

    def right_click(store: object) -> object:
        return store

    frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=250)
    frame.bind("<Button-1>", left_click("GO"))
    frame.bind("<Button-2>", right_click("STOP"))

    frame.pack()

    root.mainloop()

    return right_click == right_click(store)
```

Comment: What do you mean by not properly?

Comment: The main issues of your code are that 1) you override `left_click` and `right_click` by functions; 2) you pass result of functions instead of references to functions to `frame.bind(...)`; 3) you cannot get the return value from functions used in `bind(...)`.

Comment: Why do you say it isn't creating the frame? When I run the code, the frame gets created just as I would expect.

Comment: `<Button-2>` is middle button, `<Button-3>` is right button.

Answer (score 1):

As Bryan Oakley said your code creates `Frame` without problem.
I also don't know what you means "not properly creating a Tkinter window".

As acw1668 said you have some mistakes in code:

1. you can't use the same name for variable and function - `left_click`, `right_click`
2. `bind()` (similar to `command=` and `after()`) needs name of function - it means without `()`. It is called 'callback'. If you need to use function with arguments then you can create function without arguments which runs your function with argument. You can also use `lambda` to create this function directly in `bind()`
3. `bind()` can't get result from function so instead of using `return` you have to assign result to `global` variable and then you can get it outside function.

And my points:

1. `<Button-2>` is middle button, `<Button-3>` is right button.
2. `bind()` expects callback which gets one parameter - `event`

.

```
import tkinter as tk

def clicking_pad(worker_1):
    global left_click
    global right_click

    def on_left_click(store: object) -> object:
        #return store
        global left_click
        left_click = store
        print('[INSIDE] left_click:', left_click)

    def on_right_click(store: object) -> object:
        #return store
        global right_click
        right_click = store
        print('[INSIDE] right_click:', right_click)

    root = tk.Tk()

    frame = tk.Frame(root, width=300, height=250)
    frame.pack()

    frame.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event:on_left_click("GO"))
    frame.bind("<Button-3>", lambda event:on_right_click("STOP"))

    root.mainloop()

    print('[OUTSIDE] left_click:', left_click)
    print('[OUTSIDE] right_click:', right_click)

clicking_pad(None)
```

---

**EDIT:** Without `lambda`

```
def on_button_1(event):
    on_left_click("GO")

def on_button_3(event):
    on_right_click("STOP")

frame.bind("<Button-1>", on_button_1)
frame.bind("<Button-3>", on_button_3)
```

or if your function returns value

```
def on_button_1(event):
    global result 
    result = on_left_click("GO")

def on_button_3(event):
    global result 
    result = on_right_click("STOP")

frame.bind("<Button-1>", on_button_1)
frame.bind("<Button-3>", on_button_3)
```